# NetSuite SuiteTalk SDK

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I am not able to find the JARs for these imports and I am searching the web since 1 hour. Could somebody please attach the required JARs here. Thanks a lot.

```
import com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2021_1.RecordRef;
import com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2021_1.SearchResult;
import com.netsuite.webservices.platform.messages_2021_1.ApplicationInfo;
import com.netsuite.webservices.platform.messages_2021_1.Preferences;
import com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2021_1.NetSuitePortType;
import com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2021_1.NetSuiteServiceLocator;
```

Comment: I got sample running but it has nothing to do with Netsuite documentation. Did you get yours going?

Answer (score 0):

You don't download those jars. You generate the classes using wsdl to client generator.

Instructions for using Apache Axis 1.4 are in the Netsuite help under the SOAP Web Services Quick Start topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. For a simple test I took the demo program provided by NetSuite Team (NSJavaClient2023-1.zip) and filled all the credentials needed and ran it. I get the error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:216)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at com.netsuite.suitetalk.proxy.v2023_1.platform.NetSuiteBindingStub..
at com.netsuite.suitetalk.client.v2023_1.WsClient.callGetRecord(WsClient.java:714)

Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Using the wsdl to client generator, the main suitetalk.wsdl has references like <xsd:import namespace="urn:core_2023_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" schemaLocation="../../xsd/platform/v2023_1_0/core.xsd"/> to hundreds of locations which always require another file in another directory and all this in a recursive manner throughout all the xsd files. Somehow impossible to build such a tree. wsdl2java files exits everytime with the error can not find this or that. How do you do that?